# Installation error of Tensorflow using Python 3.7 and Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have tried many times to install Tensorflow using Python 3.7.3 and Anaconda, but get every time the same error message:

import tensorflow as tf

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

I uninstalled Python, Tensorflow and Anaconda but couldn't come any further. I also downgraded Python to 3.6.3, but it couldn't fix the problem. I have really no idea anymore. I followed an Installation guide by our university.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.11.6. Ok, I have updated the my mac but now I got this problem:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3538944ef98e> in <module>
      1 #guarantee fixed seeds for comparability
      2 np.random.seed(42)
----> 3 tf.random.set_random_seed(42)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.random' has no attribute 'set_random_seed'
```

This is the installation guide: [1](https://ibb.co/WBHnPT0)

Comment: Solved it with: `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`